# How to find by XPATH when the XPATH contains apostrophes

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1EXz.png)So im trying to find by XPATH and it contains an apostrophe like stated. So, I switched to calling these by ID instead, one of them works the second does not. So, I tried calling it by path again this time switching out single and double quotes in both locations. It works on ID gen 31 but not ID gen 140.

#full code for reference

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
edge_options = Options()
edge_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Edge(edge_options)
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.get("https://oceanspray-amc.ivanticloud.com/Account/SelectRole?returnUrl=%3FNoDefaultProvider%3DTrue&NoDefaultProvider=True/")    
driver.maximize_window()

#log in using azure AD
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/form/div[4]/div/a").click();
#Service Desk Analyst
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/form/div[3]").click();
#Submit Button
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div/form/div[4]/div/button").click();
#Service Request Button
driver.find_element(By.ID, "ext-gen31").click();

time.sleep(2)
#New Service Request Button

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"ext-gen140\"]"))).click();

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/em/button").click();

# driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"ext-gen140\"]").click()

# driver.find_element(By.ID, "ext-gen140").click();



PS C:\Users\msmith2\Desktop\Work> & C:/Users/msmith2/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.11.exe "c:/Users/msmith2/Desktop/Work/Ivanti Auto.py"
[8840:15872:0830/012912.136:ERROR:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(163)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is 
not enabled.
[8840:15872:0830/012912.164:ERROR:assistance_home_client.cc(32)] File path C:\Users\msmith2\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir17404_1882902945\Default

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50390/devtools/browser/ec2311c1-7749-49e9-8714-1ff0f21680fe
[8840:15872:0830/012913.317:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(124)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. 
If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782. 
[8840:15872:0830/012916.194:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(124)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. 
If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\msmith2\Desktop\Work\Ivanti Auto.py", line 29, in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"ext-gen140\"]"))).click();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\msmith2\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6FA243D72+61490]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF6FA1D5FC2+740594]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F9FAB8AE]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F9FF32F4]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F9FF3405]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6FA02FCE7]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6FA01394F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F9FE7021]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6FA02CE21]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6FA0136E3]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F9FE5EAA]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F9FE518B]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6F9FE6634]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF6FA408D29+1207369]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF6FA065304]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF6FA1290E1+32273]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF6FA1219D9+1801]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF6FA407904+1202212]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF6FA1DE958+19784]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF6FA1DAE14+4612]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogConfiguration::operator* [0x00007FF6FA1DAF46+4918]
        Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF6FA1CF411+713025]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFF13D07614+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFF140226B1+33]
```

Without hovering over

```
<table id="ext-comp-1050" cellspacing="0" class="x-btn   x-btn-noicon " style="width: auto;"><tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left"><tr><td class="x-btn-tl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-tc"></td><td class="x-btn-tr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr><tr><td class="x-btn-ml"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-mc"><em class="" unselectable="on"><button type="button" id="ext-gen142" class=" x-btn-text" tabindex="-1">New</button></em></td><td class="x-btn-mr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr><tr><td class="x-btn-bl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-bc"></td><td class="x-btn-br"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Hovering over

```
<table id="ext-comp-1050" cellspacing="0" class="x-btn   x-btn-noicon  x-btn-over " style="width: auto;"><tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left"><tr><td class="x-btn-tl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-tc"></td><td class="x-btn-tr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr><tr><td class="x-btn-ml"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-mc"><em class="" unselectable="on"><button type="button" id="ext-gen142" class=" x-btn-text" tabindex="-1">New</button></em></td><td class="x-btn-mr"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr><tr><td class="x-btn-bl"><i>&nbsp;</i></td><td class="x-btn-bc"></td><td class="x-btn-br"><i>&nbsp;</i></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: It looks like you're dealing with Selenium and XPATH for web automation.

Comment: Yes, apologies I am dealing with selenium for python using web driver and trying to find elements by XPATH and then click the elements

Comment: @Roamer can you share at least a part of HTML structure as far as we don't have Azure accounts?

Comment: Sure what are you wanting me to share?
Do you just want me to copy and paste the HTML structure.

Comment: Ive tried adding the HTML structure every variation I've tried says it's to many characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can try finding the xpath like this (single quotes within the double quotes)

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='ext-gen140']").click();
```

or use the escape sequence

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"ext-gen140\"]").click()
```

Comment: Neither of these options seemed to do the trick both are giving the same error code

  File "c:\Users\msmith2\Desktop\Work\Ivanti Auto.py", line 30, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"ext-gen140\"]").click()

Comment: Could you provide the link for that page and error details?

Comment: https://oceanspray-amc.ivanticloud.com/Account/SelectRole?returnUrl=%3FNoDefaultProvider%3DTrue&NoDefaultProvider=True/

This is the link but you need an account to log in so not sure if you will be able to get in ill add the error notes to my post since they are pretty long

Comment: The commented lines are the different variations Ive tried, I had the time.sleep there to see if it was running to soon but doesnt seem to effect it at all
if you want I can provide screen shots of the website and the xpath I grabbed?

Comment: yes, please provide the screenshots.

Comment: screen shot added to the top of the post for example of the website.

Comment: Try using the webdriver wait (make the webdriver to wait until the element is visible or clickable)

Comment: I'm using driver.implicity.wait(20) towards the top of the code right after calling the webdriver, Do I need to use it again?

Comment: Use explicit wait
`element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"ext-gen140\"]")))`
element.click();

Comment: I got it loaded into the code but its give me another error
File "c:\Users\msmith2\Desktop\Work\Ivanti Auto.py", line 29, in <module>
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"ext-gen140\"]"))).click();
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: So i think i found the problem but i can find the solution im uploading it above but basically one of the options changes when you hover over the button which changes the element to x-btn-over,  it also has <em class="" unselectable="on">